# Taking animations to the next level with React Native

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native

I've been working with React-Native for a few months now and I think it's time for me to try to take my applications to the next level with sweet animations and smooth user experience.

Here is an example of the effects and experience I'd like to reproduce :

[image: Dribbble post by Cynthia]

You can see the full Dribbble post here : https://dribbble.com/shots/3582624-ticket-recommend (not mine)

What I personally like about this example is the smooth scrolling effect and the feeling you get. I tried to get a similar feedback using ScrollView and onScroll event to animate each item, but it's not not very conclusive so far.

I know my question is quite an open one and not really about a specific component from React-Native but I'd like us to share our best practices and ideas to get to create this kind of applications.

So feel free to let me know if you've ever created or builded this sort of animations or if you have somewhere in your bookmarks a link to a tutorial or a github to help me to understand how it works.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : just to be clear, I know this is a wide range topic but what I'm looking for here is a constructive discussion with people sharing their experiences (over opinions) backed up with facts and references.

Comment: flagging for closure as it is an opinion-based question asking for tutorial recommendations and not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Well, okay @BJHStudios but where or how I am supposed to find the good ressources and the user experience from other developers then?

Comment: There are plenty of groups and discussion forums online where this would be an appropriate question. Stack Overflow is not intended to be a place for constructive discussion on wide topics, but rather a place to ask specific programming questions and get clear specific answers.